# EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 3 result set

Tags: r, sql-server, ssms, resultset

I'm trying to create a stored procedure using R code top build a ML Model in SQL Server.

```
            predictions = rxPredict(model, Pred_Data);
            OutputDataSet <- cbind(Pred_Data$key1,Pred_Data$flag,predictions);'
                , @input_data_1 = @q
                , @params = N'@rx_model varbinary(max)'
                , @rx_model = @rx_model
                WITH RESULT SETS (("key1" varchar(20),"flag" varchar(10),"predictions" FLOAT));
```

I was able to create my stored procedure with no error.

I am getting this error when trying to save output in a table.

```
STDOUT message(s) from external script: 
Rows Read: 0, Total Rows Processed: 0, Total Chunk Time: 0.001 seconds
```

> Msg 11537, Level 16, State 3, Line 59
> EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 3 column(s) for result set number 1, but the statement sent 2 column(s) at run time.

I've included all three columns mentioned in `"With Result Sets"` in my output code structure. I followed similar structure for other stored procedures. No issues at all.

Can anyone tell me what could be the real issue in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

There were no datapoints to make **predictions** on. Hence it was sending only outputs for two columns.